# Exporting Reports from SSRS Report Manager

Tags: reporting-services

I have several SSRS reports which have a textbox at the bottom with a link to a privacy notice page. Some of my users will export these reports to an Excel workbook or a Word document. When the users export the reports, the reporting engine does ***not*** include the link in the office documents. When exported as as PDF or HTML, the link to the notice ***is*** also exported as expected. Is there a way for me to configure or force the office documents to include the link to the notice and ensure that it is also exported?

Comment: Are putting the textbox in the footer or body section?  Using SSRS 2005, I confirmed that none of the info in my footer (includes a hyperlink) appears in an Excel export.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The textbox containing the link **has** to be in the body section when exporting to Excel.

Comment: The textbox is on the body section but still not displaying in Excel. I am using SSRS 2008.

Comment: I'm using 2005.  How are you defining the url?  Mine has the www.domain.com as the value/expression, nothing else.

Comment: I am using a regular textbox which has text similar to this: "Copyright 2009 Company Name - Privacy Notice" The Privacy Notice part is a link to another SSRS report which has only the privacy text in it. This text box in in the body of the report right under a Tablix control.

Comment: There must be a way to show/hide footer/textbox-at-the-end based on whether the format requested is EXCEL or other